# Unable to connect to SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am learning C# and I am trying to connect my program to a SQL Server database. For the learning purpose I followed the following video :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rwdedptaou0

This is my code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestDBMS
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand cmd;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Reventon\Documents\EmployeeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Table VALUES(3, 'Sachin', '120000', 'Nagaur')";
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling the program I am getting an error

> Incorrect Syntax Near the 'Table'

(for better representation i have captured the screenshot and uploaded on my Skydrive account). 
http://sdrv.ms/1bUDe3l

Please help me out.

Comment: I tried changing Table name but everything i am changing the name and pressing the save button the Save Dialogue Box is keep appearing to enter name again and again.

Please checkout the ScreenShot : 
http://sdrv.ms/LTvowG

Comment: @press update dont press save..!! :) it works..:)

Comment: run the query which i gave you.. it works

Comment: i have updated my answer, check for it..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Insert Query Syntax:**

```
INSERT INTO yourtablename
(column1, column2, ... )
VALUES
(expression1, expression2, ... );
```

The error in your code is the `table` rename it to the appropriate table name
like **Customertable**

```
INSERT INTO Customertable VALUES(3, 'Sachin', '120000', 'Nagaur')
```

**Alter table name:**

Use sp_rename to rename your table name:

```
    EXEC sp_rename 'table', 'Customertable'

    sp_rename old_table_name , new_table_name
```

**`ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME RENAME TO NEW_TABLE_NAME`** Works only in **Oracle DB**.

**[Tutorial](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/)**

You can find documentation on this procedure on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

In **Server Explorer** right click on **Views** and click **New Query**.
use this code to rename table:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Table', 'NewName'
```

then click on **Execute** button.
after **5-30** seconds in **server explorer** click on **refresh** button.

[image]

Comment: Do i need to use SQL Server, Isn't it possible to change it via Visual Studio only?

Comment: no to change the table name you should be using the database engine..!! i.e sql server

Comment: Yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss. Its Done :) I am happy

Comment: Thank you so much. Sir can you guide me that which book i should learn to know this connectivity aspects?

Comment: Glat that it helped..! :) Happy coding..! :)

Answer (score 4):

`Table` is keyword , can't be used as tablename. 
Change query to

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO yourTableName VALUES(3, 'Sachin', '120000', 'Nagaur')";
```

Comment: But sir, it was the default name of the table, Should i change it to any anonymous name?

Comment: Yes sir, change table name in database and then in code, the word Table is a SQL keyword .

Comment: Unable to Change Table name : 
I tried changing Table name but everything i am changing the name and pressing the save button the Save Dialogue Box is keep appearing to enter name again and again. Please checkout the ScreenShot : sdrv.ms/LTvowG

Answer (score 0):

**Table** is a default SQL keyword. Give specific name to your table.

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(3, 'Sachin', '120000', 'Nagaur')
```

Comment: How can i change the table name?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886786/how-do-i-rename-the-table-name-using-sql-query) You can see how to change the table name!

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name
  RENAME TO new_table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your tablename?? and try again.Because table is a default keyword

```
INSERT INTO Tablename (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES(3, 'Sachin', '120000', 'Nagaur')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `Table` keyword as tablename. You should give some other name. Here is list of keywords in `SQL Server`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Try this query :

```
string query = "INSERT INTO yourTableName VALUES (3, 'Sachin', '120000', 'Nagaur')";
```

OR

```
string query = "INSERT INTO yourTableName(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) VALUES (3, 'Sachin', '120000', 'Nagaur')";
```

Comment: Unable to Change Table name : 
I tried changing Table name but everything i am changing the name and pressing the save button the Save Dialogue Box is keep appearing to enter name again and again. Please checkout the ScreenShot : sdrv.ms/LTvowG

Comment: Change your table name to `DemoTable` and in `Insert` query also

Comment: But I see it in you database. change it in database also

Answer (score 0):

Actually while all but one of the answers are correct, you CAN actually use the word Table as a table name, if you use square brackets `[ ]`

```
Create Table Table ( id int ) -- doesn't work!
```

However,

```
Create Table [Table] ( id int ) -- works!
```

I don't recommend this practice and agree it's best to use a name other than `"Table"` even with square brackets for your database table!

Just wanted to point out that technically speaking, there is actually a way to use the SQL keyword 'table' as a table name in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [Table] VALUES(3, 'Sachin', '120000', 'Nagaur')";
```