# Rename all tables in SELECT query

Tags: sql, apache-calcite

Can anyone tell me how to replace the name of all the table names in a the SELECT/FROM statements?. I'm looking of a way that works well across vanilla queries as well as more complex ones with sub-queries and joins.

I.e.

New table name:  new_table
Original query:  `SELECT * from table`;

Result query: `SELECT * FROM new_table`;

Thanks a lot,

j

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a table name using an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886786/how-to-change-a-table-name-using-an-sql-query)

Comment: I really didn't get your question so you need to alias your table with another name during initializing your query or you need to rename the entire table name.

Comment: Based on a quick glance at the Apache Calcite website, it supports a very standard SQL syntax which means you should be able to do "Select * from table as 'new_table'" The word "as" may or may not be needed. I have not used Apache Calcite so I'm not positive of that as an answer.

Comment: Use regex perhaps?

Comment: One of Calcite's features is an SQL Parser.  I want to be able to parse the original query and navigate to all of the apropiate SqlIdentifier  nodes that contain a table name so that I can change the actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are as simple as what you're proposing, you should be able start by [parsing the query](https://github.com/michaelmior/calcite-notebooks/blob/master/query-parsing.ipynb) which will give you a `SqlSelect` object. From there you can use `getFrom` to check if it's the table you want to change and `setFrom` to change it.

If you want to handle more complex queries, you should be able to implement the `SqlVisitor` interface to find all occurrences of the table to replace.

Comment: My queries are definitely not that simple :)  They can be extremely complex.  I implemented an SqlVisitor and noticed that things got complicated really quickly. The biggest issue is it's hard to know if the SqlIdentifier is a table-name, a field, etc ..

Comment: On a similar note, I'm wondering if there's any easy way to know how many different tables a query references.

Comment: You're right that in general, it's a hard problem. I would suggest starting with the simplest possible case you outlined above and write a test and then continue expanding and writing tests. Ultimately I'm not sure there's a great way to ensure that you cover every possible case, but it shouldn't be too tough to cover a reasonable class of queries.